# Running a Multiple Angular 6 Project in Single Root Folder on Apache

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, angular6

I have created two different individual angular apps that I now have to place under one folder.

For example: `www.example.com/beta3/`

So the two apps will be `www.example.com/beta3/app1` and `www.example.com/beta3/app2`

I have configured the `HashLocationStrategy` for app1 and also configured the htaccess file.  Everything works fine for app1, but when I reload app2 it always goes back to app1.

My .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/beta3/app1 [R=301,L] 
Options -Indexes
```

How can I manage these two apps simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command for each project to be run simultaneously on single folder.

```
ng build --prod --base-href /beta3/app1

ng build --prod --base-href /beta3/app2
```